# Which is the best sample/approach to start openiddict server to provide logins to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, oauth, single-sign-on, openiddict

We have a client database (Username, Passwordhash, Address...) sitting on an MSSQL table on a windows server.
Now we are creating a Wordpress/Woocommerce Site on Linux server and want to SSO into wordpress based on the above mentioned credentials.
We do not want to use other technologies besides C#/.Net.
So we found "Openiddict".
Which is the best sample/way to set it up fast?

- a) Use one of the samples at:
  https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples (which one?)
- b) Use https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/dev/docs/reference/modules/OpenId/
  (Orchard-Core and it's OpenID-Module based on Openiddict?)
- c) Use a different sample out there? Someone else did that
  before?

On the Wordpress-Side it looks that plugin should be compatible?
https://github.com/pealmeid/openid-connect-generic

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which is the best sample/way to set it up fast?

The OrchardCore OpenID module (indeed based on OpenIddict) is great if you're looking for something simple and that can be configured using a GUI.
If you're not against adding some code, using OpenIddict directly is a good option that will offer you much more flexibility. For that, take a look at the code flow sample here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia

(you can read more about the differences between the various flows here: https://documentation.openiddict.com/guides/choosing-the-right-flow.html)